# Is there a way to search Github for specific text from PDF resources

Tags: github, github-search

Is there an easy to search for specific text in GitHub?

Like the way we can search for "code" in GitHub, is there an easy way to do a search for keywords using the Github search from all the PDF files that are there in the GitHub.

Comment: I suspect the answer is no, because extracting usable text from a PDF is rather involved and I don't think GitHub does any sort of special parsing on files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's available that kind of search on github, but you can try by google in this way:

```
python class filetype:pdf site:github.com
```

Comment: [this is the search](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&ei=SjbdX76rNsOTkwWIybq4CQ&q=python+class+filetype%3Apdf+site%3Agithub.com&oq=python+class+filetype%3Apdf+site%3Agithub.com&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQR1CaHliaHmCpJmgAcAJ4AIABYYgBYZIBATGYAQCgAQKgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEGwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi--MDt0tjtAhXDyaQKHYikDpcQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) what's miss @Exploring ?